# use Kubernetes service account from different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a service account SA1 in namespace NS1 and set a full configuration for SA1 (workload identity in GCP).
I need to use the service account SA1 in pods from different namespaces.
for now I have the pods in namespace NS1 using the SA1

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
  namespace: NS1
spec:
  serviceAccountName: SA1
```

Answer (score 2):

ServiceAccount is a namespaced resource in Kubernetes, meaning that it can only be referenced from pods deployed in the same namespace.

This is by design, Namespaces act as logical containers on which you apply access policies and a pod in one namespace should not be able to "steal" the serviceaccount from another (possibly unrelated) namespace

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? Roles and RoleBindings are also namespaced, yet can reference service accounts in a different namespace.

Comment: You can refer to the Service Account part in the [Pod API spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#service-account). As you can see there is no way to specify namespace, and since service accounts are a namespaced resource it implies that only service accounts from the same namespace can be referenced. If you instead look at the [Subject part of the RoleBinding API spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/authorization-resources/role-binding-v1/) there is a field to specify which namespace the service account belongs to

Comment: This is not correct, the examples in: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-binding-examples show that you can bind roles to service accounts from other namespaces

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to as not correct? The OP question is about assigning a service account to a pod where the SA and pod is in different namespaces, which is not possible. However as you rightly point out (and which is mentioned in previously comments as well) an SA can be assigned a role from a different namespace, but that was not the question being asked.